# Finding out the number of zeros at the end of a number. What's wrong with my code? Whatever the input is the output is always '0'

Tags: python

```
def end_zeros(int):
    c = str(int)
    d = c.split()
    count = 0
    for i in d[len(d):0:-1]:
        if i == 0:
            count = count + 1
        
        else:
            break
    return (count)
```

print(end_zeros(312124000400000))

#It outputs '0' while it should be 5

Comment: i is a string so you should be comparing it with "0" not 0. Change if i == 0: to if i == "0":

Comment: A string can never equal the number 0.

Comment: Why are you calling split? Also, don't use `int` as a variable name: it shadows a very common builtin function. Also, your list slicing has an off by one error: the second index should be -1 to visit all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
def end_zeros(n):
    d = str(n)
    count = 0
    for i in d[len(d):0:-1]:
        if i == '0':
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    return count
```

You don't need to split the string. And you can't compare 0 to '0'.

Edit: `for i in d[::-1]:` works as well.

Comment: I think you don't need the length and 0 in the slice, you can just use `for i in d[::-1]:`

Comment: There is an error in your answer...

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO I wasn't able to find the error. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, there's no error, I was convinced of that because of that break after finding a non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Just to round out the answers, you could use `rstrip()` along with `len()` here:

```
def end_zeros(n):
    c = str(n)
    return len(c) - len(c.rstrip('0'))

print(end_zeros('312124000400000'))  # 5
```

Answer (score 1):

String manipulation seems to be a rather bizarre approach to something that's essentially arithmetic. I suggest:

```
def end_zeros(n):
    c = 0
    m = 10
    while m <= n and n % m == 0:
        c += 1
        m *= 10
    return c

print(end_zeros(312124000400000))
```

**Output:**

```
5
```

**Note:**

There remains the question of what the answer should be if *n* is zero. Perhaps an explicit test for zero returning 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the argument in the `split` function. Although that will only remove the zeroes prevent you from counting it. Check the following:

```
n = 31210024000400000
s = str(n)
print(s.split("0")) #['3121', '', '24', '', '', '4', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Convert the num into string and count for zeroes in reverse and break when first non zero appears.

```
cntr=0
for ch in s[::-1]:
    if ch == '0':
        cntr+=1
    else:
        break
print(cntr)
```

Comment: That'll count the zeros in the middle of the number as well...

Comment: @JiříBaum Sorry, I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```py
from itertools import takewhile

def end_zeros(n):
    return sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x == '0', reversed(str(n))))
```

Or, using builtin functions only (`next()` and `enumerate()`): Find the index of the first nonzero character of the reversed string.

```py
def end_zeros(n):
    c = str(n)
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(c)) if x != '0'), len(c))
```